# Split or identify records based off number of join/where conditions satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have 2 tables that are joined on 5 fields that exist in both tables:

```
firstname
lastname
address
city
country
```

What is the most efficient way in determining records where all match, any 4 match, any 3 match, any 2 match, 1 match, no match.

Originally, I was thinking of just puting all 5 in the join condition with **AND** so I would get the all 5 match records and 0 match records (I used left join and would check for null on one of the fields in the right table). From the list of Null's I could check for each condition using the same left join and union them all filtering the values with null's or the # of nulls to determine my matches.

I am sure there is a better way in doing this. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

```
SELECT *, cast(count1 as int)+cast(count2 as int)+cast(count3 as int)+cast(count4 as int)+cast(count5 as int)
FROM(
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, 
    t1.firstname = t2.firstname as count1, 
    t1.lastname = t2.lastname as count2,
    t1.address = t2.address as count3,
    t1.city = t2.city as count4,
    c1.country = t2.country as count5
FROM Table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 AS t2) t3
```

Comment: Do you have any Sample data we can look at to determine how to do it? However I think i might be able to see a solution involving CTE's if its how i imagine it to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` that creates a full cross-product between the two tables. Then add up the number of columns that match between each pair of records.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, 
    (t1.firstname = t2.firstname) + (t1.lastname = t2.lastname) + (t1.address = t2.address) + (t1.city = t2.city) + (c1.country = t2.country) AS num_fields_matching
FROM Table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 AS t2
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, Is there a reason my num_fields_matching is coming up as boolean (true,false,null) rather than a number that represents the count?

Comment: Oops, needed parentheses because `+` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: cool! I had to cast everything to int but realized that was unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: In MySQL, true and false automatically convert to 1 and 0.